# I'm getting a strange error when using "color:"

Tags: flutter, button, colors, styles

I get this error when using `color:`

The named parameter 'color' isn't defined.

code is:

```
body: Center(
  child: ElevatedButton(
    child: Text('click'),
    onPressed: () {}  ,
    color: Colors.green[300],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type style then next is this

```dart
  ElevatedButton(
   style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
     primary: Colors.green[300],
        ),
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text("click"),
   ),
```